# FancyBox 2 YouTube wmode parameter not activating

Tags: jquery, parameters, fancybox, fancybox-2, wmode

For some reason I can't get absolutely position elements with a `z-index` set to `9999` to appear over my FancyBox with YouTube `iframe`, even though I have my `wmode` parameter set to `opaque`, even the 'X' close button:

FancyBox v2.1.3

FancyBox Media v1.0.5

JS:

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {

        $('#splash-video')
            .fancybox({
                fitToView : true,
                width     : '100%',
                height    : '100%',
                margin    : 10,
                padding   : 0,
                helpers   : {
                    media : true
                },
                youtube : {
                    params : {
                        autoplay : 1,
                        fs       : 1,
                        hd       : 1,
                        rel      : 0,
                        showinfo : 0,
                        wmode    : 'opaque' // this no worky
                    }
                }
            });

        $('.skip-video').on('click', function() {
            $.fancybox.close();
            $(this).remove();
        });

        setTimeout(function() {
            $.fancybox.close();
            $('.skip-video').remove();
        }, 64000);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

HTML:

```
<a id="splash-video" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"></a>
<a href="#" class="skip-video">Skip Video</a>
```

The above activates my FancyBox which is then click-triggered to appear, while having my `.skip-video` anchor position over the top, but it doesn't.

Both transparent and opaque seem to have no effect on any browser; the "X" close button and div are above the YouTube video in Chrome, but literally no other major browser (FF, IE7-9, Opera and Safari).

All in all, I think none of the YouTube params are working.

**UPDATE:**

It's working now thanks to [Janis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/486595/janis)' help :).
I altered my Fancybox JS to:

```
$('#splash-video')
    .fancybox({
        fitToView : true,
        width     : '100%',
        height    : '100%',
        margin    : 0,
        padding   : 0
    });
```

and changed the anchor to:

```
<a id="splash-video" class="fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/opj24KnzrWo?autoplay=1&amp;autohide=1&amp;fs=1&amp;rel=0&amp;hd=1&amp;wmode=opaque&amp;enablejsapi=1"></a>
```

Great success!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Why do you think that none of the params are working? Is your video auto-starting? If you check developer tools, does the iframe source looks like this?
   `http://www.youtube.com/embed/opj24KnzrWo?autoplay=1&autohide=1&fs=1&rel=0&hd=1&wmode=opaque&enablejsapi=1`
   If yes, then the script works perfectly fine.
2. I do not know how exactly are you trying to get absolutely position elements to appear over the fancyBox and why it is not working for you, but this works fine for me:

   ```
   $(".fancybox")
   .attr('rel', 'gallery')
   .fancybox({
       openEffect  : 'none',
       closeEffect : 'none',
       nextEffect  : 'none',
       prevEffect  : 'none'
   });​
   ```

   [Test case](http://jsfiddle.net/NcQ2u/).

Comment: No the iframe url was not that, it was the default one in the media js file, I was looking around on here and elsewhere that you override it with the params, but I literally just added class="fancybox.iframe" and that full href string above and it worked <3 Thank you so much! Awesome plugin btw, been using it for years :D